# How to flag a self answer for an off-topic question?

Tags: discussion, flags, scope, self-answer

I just came across this self answered question: [C++ library gets download/upload rates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949565/c-library-gets-download-upload-rates)

> ### C++ library gets download/upload rates
>
> I'm lost. I don't know where to look. I am looking for a c++ library which 
>   allows to know simply the current rate of download and/or upload of
>   the computer.
>
> For example, the computer downloads a file at 2 Mb/s and a stream at 1
>   Mb/s. The library gives me the indication 3 Mb/s (maybe even better by
>   specifying which program uses what rate? )
>
> Yes, I am very optimistic about the existence of such a library.
>
> Or maybe another language than c++ ?
>
> Thank you.
>
> [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dll) [static-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-libraries)

The question is clearly off topic regarding point #4 of the help center [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) article:

> 4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Finally the OP decided to self-answer that question with a link to a suitable project they found:

> I found this project : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6259/Monitoring-network-speed
>
> huhuhu

I wasn't sure how to flag that answer. VLQ or NAA?
Should I flag it at all?

I believe that answering off-topic questions is bad in general, because other users seeing that may feel encouraged to ask more off-topic questions of that kind.

(The question has since been deleted, but my question remains the same.)

Comment: It would be nice if a +10 user may add a screenshot of the deleted stuff.

Comment: @gnat Not really. It's an edge case.

Comment: per my reading it's a textbook case covered by "another castle" guidance. Answer is link-only while question doesn't ask for links meaning it qualifies for NAA. (question should be closed as library recommendation but that's tangential)

Comment: Re [your comment on this now deleted question about account merging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355996/how-to-decide-which-account-gets-deleted-when-merging-two-accounts): [Posting on a child meta is absolutely fine!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89232/288751). People can post bug reports or other network-wide questions on whatever child meta the feel most comfortable posting on. One thing to think about is that on Over Meta, downvotes count, on Meta Stack Overflow, downvotes are free. This lowers the emotional bar of entry for posting such questions, which should be fostered

Answer (score 9):

First off, just to be clear, asking and answering your own question is *encouraged* here, so that's not an issue. I suspect you know this, but we do get some flags from people who are unaware of this and feel it might be abusive behavior, so I just want to state clearly that it is not.

However, asking off-topic questions is a problem. It really doesn't matter whether you're self-answering the off-topic questions, or just asking them—the questions are still off-topic, and a pattern of asking off-topic questions is something that needs to be addressed.

The way you address it is by flagging/voting to close the question as off-topic. One of the standard reasons apply here, so there's really nothing more that needs to be done.

If you wanted to flag the link-only answer as "not an answer", that would have been okay, too. It is definitely link-only: the link text itself cannot stand alone as the answer, and the *entirety* of the answer is buried behind the link. There's no redeeming content once you strip away the markdown, so it qualifies for NAA. Plus, there's that "huhuhu" nonsense—an obvious attempt to work around the quality filter—which just about justifies a flag on its own.

You can get into an extended debate about whether "not an answer" or "very low quality" is better. Avoid the temptation. If you see an answer that needs to be removed, pick whichever of those two flags strikes your fancy and raise it. I don't know any moderator who agonizes over the difference between NAA and VLQ, and regular users certainly don't, since both dump posts into the same Low Quality Posts review queue. In fact, most of us feel that NAA and VLQ should be combined into a single flag, indicating an unsalvageable answer that needs to be deleted. Tempting as it may be to interpret "very low quality" as a "requires editing" flag, that's not what it is.

Of course, flagging the answer would rather be missing the point, since the question is what was causing harm. If we get the question closed and deleted, then the low-quality answer(s) will disappear along with it, so it's hardly worth wasting time worrying about deleting individual answers to off-topic questions.

And don't forget to downvote both the question and the answer.

huhuhu

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find a suitable flag, that usually means that the post shouldn't be flagged.  There isn't a generic flag for "I don't like what this user is doing here", so if it doesn't fit one of the existing flags, it often means that it shouldn't be flagged.

In this specific case, the fact that it was a self answer doesn't make it special.  The answer does address the question asked (at least based on your description, I can't see the post myself).  So that means there is nothing to flag.  That being said, the question is still off-topic so you should be handling the question itself by voting to close it using the option you mentioned in your question.

Of course, none of this means that the answer is high quality or helpful, so downvoting could be completely appropriate.  Likewise, if you discover this is a pattern of behavior for the user (asking and self-answering off-topic questions), you can certainly raise a custom moderator flag and explaining the situation in brief detail.  The moderator will look into the situation and address it directly with the user if needed.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I already handled the question itself with an appropriate close vote. Though I thought I should do something with the (self) answer as well.